# Flutter call child state method from parent

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a Parent widget which has appBar. On the appBar I have placed a save button. Now in the Parent widget's `build(BuildContext context)` method I have called a child Widget, which shows Input fields

When the user provides some input in the fields and presses the save button I want to save the data which is in the child Widget.

So the question is how can I call the child the method from the parent Widget.

I have created the obj of Child and calling that method from the Parent but it didn't work, as the function details are in the state of the child

**Parent:**

```
class AddRecipe extends StatelessWidget {

   AddRecipeInput obj;

   void save() {
   }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.save
            ),
            onPressed: save, // Save action on which i want to trigger child
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Add a new recipe to help other foodies like you!!'),
            obj = AddRecipeInput()
          ],
        ),
      )),
  }
```

**Child:**

```
class AddRecipeInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddRecipeInputState createState() => _AddRecipeInputState();
}

class _AddRecipeInputState extends State<AddRecipeInput> {
  void prepareAddrecipe() {}
}
```

As shown in above example I want to call `prepareAddrecipe` of `AddRecipeInput` on the pressed event of `save` function from `AddRecipe`

Comment: post your code as it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @pskink I have added sample code

Comment: the easiest way is to use `ScopedModel` / `Provider` or similar packages

Comment: The best way to handle your state is Providers. This medium link will help you to use Provider
[Flutter StateManagement with Provider](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-statemanagement-with-provider-ee251bbc5ac1)